# Adding superscript in SAS based on pvalues

Tags: arrays, loops, sas

I'd like to add a 'superscript' notation to the results of multiple comparisons analysis if a p-value is less than 0.05. For example, I have the following results:

```
Group                Comparison                 Pvalue             CI_Diff
Subgroup1            GroupA vs. GroupB          .002               9.78(7.3, 11.8)
Subgroup1            GroupA vs. GroupC          .38                1.2(-.7,3.9)
Subgroup1            GroupB vs. GroupC          .001               20(12.3,35.6)
```

I would then like to have the following table:

```
Subgroup             CI_Diff
1.GroupA             9.78(7.3, 11.8)^{super 2,3}
2.GroupB             1.2(-.7,3.9)^{super 1}
3.GroupC             20(12.3,35.6)^{super 1}
```

The 'superscripts' denote the Subgroup having a p-value less than 0.05 when compared with the group in the bracket characters. I'd like to have code that would allow for multiple Subgroups beyond Subgroup1.

Here is what I have so far:

```
IF Comparison = 'GroupA vs. GroupB' < .05 THEN 
DO;
   SUBGROUP = GROUPA;
   CI_DIFF = CATX(CI_DIFF, ^{super 2,3};
END;
```

Any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: What are the rules for mapping "*group-P* vs *group-Q*" to "*sequence-number*. Group ??"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix a couple of things

- For each `comparison` value

  - map the "Group*P* vs. Group*Q*" to the desired `subgroup` value
  - compare `Pvalue` to `0.05` for the superscript concatenation needed for the comparison
- quote the inline ODS formatted text that is being concatenated to `CI_DIFF`.
- The function should be `CATS` instead of `CATX`.
  *`CATX` is used when you want to also add a separator between the values being concatenated.*
- The `CI_DIFF` modification might be safer in a new variable.
  *If not, the `CI_DIFF` could be modified if the code is re-run in the SAS session.*
- Ensure the ODS escape character setting matches the introducer (`^`) you chose to be used in the decoration.

Fix:

```
CI_DIFF_DECORATED = CI_DIFF;

select (comparison);
  when ('GroupA vs. GroupB') do; 
    SUBGROUP = "1. GroupA";
    if Pvalue < 0.05 then CI_DIFF_DECORATED = CATS(CI_DIFF, "^{super 2,3}");
  end;
  when ('GroupA vs. GroupC') do;
    SUBGROUP = "2. GroupB";
    if Pvalue < 0.05 then CI_DIFF_DECORATED = CATS(CI_DIFF, "^{super 1}");
  end;
  when ('GroupB vs. GroupC') do;
    SUBGROUP = "3. GroupC";
    if Pvalue < 0.05 then CI_DIFF_DECORATED = CATS(CI_DIFF, "^{super 1}");
  end;
  otherwise;
end;
```

Example:

```
data want;
  set sashelp.class;
  name_decorated = cats(name, "^{super  "||sex||" }", " ^{super 2,3}");
  label name_decorated = 'Name';
run;

ods html;

ods escapechar = "^";

proc print noobs label data=want;
  var name_decorated age weight;
run;
```

[image]